# What is the difference between these two java codes?

Tags: javascript

I have run my code witch is the first one in the sequence and then I have run the example code which is the second one in the sequences. The second one in the sequence will run but the first one will not run. What am I doing incorrectly? I have scoured the code and cannot see any differences that would matter. Coding bat tells me that the error is "cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class var line:2"

Here is the code:

```
public int diff21(int n) {
  var diff = Math.abs(n - 21);
  if (n > 21) {
    return diff*2;
  } else {
    return diff;
  }
}
public int diff21(int n) {
  if (n <= 21) {
    return 21 - n;
  } else {
    return (n - 21) * 2;
  }
}
```

Comment: Well what do you think the difference is? Looks an awful lot like homework... And `var` should be `int.

Comment: What do you think `var` does in Java? You know it's not the same as Java*Script*?

Comment: It looks like you need to read some basic tutorials before you try to write code.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I have gone through all of code academy java tutorials, but I am noticing some odd differences in what coding bat says is correct and what code academy says is correct. For instance to check equality coding bat says that a==b is the proper syntax to check if variable a and b are equal. However in code academy the proper syntax is a===b. So I am not sure which one to use. I have also attempted to set the var to class int but it does not work.

Comment: When (var dif =) is changed to (int diff =)  the new error code is that this: missing '}' or illegal start of expression. However I have had my friends check and they say nothing is wrong. Thanks for the help

Comment: @Trea704 In java there is no `===` operator. I suggest you to check which language you are using and change the question tags accordingly

Comment: You need smarter friends, @Trea704. There's a lot wrong with your code. Also with your remarks, which provide woefully incomplete information and don't answer the questions people ask you. `var` is not a primitive type! What is the _exact_ text of your error messages? What do you think `var` is? What is the rest of the class code in which your methods reside? Who told you Java has a `===` operator? It doesn't. Have you even looked at the Java Tutorial?

Comment: My apologize I see I have tagged this under Java and not JavaScript. Sorry for all of the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Java doesn't have the keyword 'var', you need to explicitly declare a variable.

In your case, you need to declare diff to be an 'int'

Answer (score 0):

`var diff` means that you are declaring a variable called `diff` of type `var`.  What is type `var`?  The compiler doesn't know, and thus the error.

Comment: Thank you. I have tried this but changed it back to the code you see know because I am running out of options. When I change the class to int I get another error code that says: missing '}' or illegal start of expression. No matter what I do I cannot get this error to go away, and I just can't see any difference between the code that runs and the code that won't.

Answer (score 0):

Change the `var` to `double` since `var` is not Java primitive data type. You can also use `int` but then you must type cast the `Math.abs`. Your code with `var` will not compile if you run the code.

If you want to test them make some changes as following.

```
public class Test {
public static void main(String[]args){
   System.out.println(diff21(10) +" "+ diff22(15));
}
public static int diff21(int n) {
    int diff = Math.abs(n - 21);
    if (n > 21) {
        return diff*2;
    } else {
        return diff;
    }
}
public static int diff22(int n) {
    if (n <= 21) {
        return 21 - n;
    } else {
        return (n - 21) * 2;
    }
  }
}
```